# Cannot fire and catch event using gwt-channel-api when onMessage() is called

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, channel-api

I'm using GWT + App engine channel api, and I want to fire an event when a message is received.
I created an interface DataUpdateHanlder (extends EventHandler) and a class DataUpdateEvent (extends GwtEvent) and I use addHandler(...) and fireEvent(...) methods in SimpleEventBus to register handlers and treat events when a message is received.
The problem is that although the event is fired, the event does not reach it's handler (nothing happens onDispatch(event) ).

If I just create and use a simple interface, and just call it's method, everything works ok (but then i have to create a list of objects for each class that wants to handle onMessage(...)).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the 'accept' thing - is what you 'are be doing wrong'

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could tell me at least a reason for that :)

Comment: actually, I meant, why is that relevant to my original question, but I will search the answer for this last question myself :)